# LinqToSql returns null when using Single - not sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linq help - Sql trace returns result, but datacontext returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579164/linq-help-sql-trace-returns-result-but-datacontext-returning-null)

[Question 1579164](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579164/linq-help-sql-trace-returns-result-but-datacontext-returning-null)

I tried changing to .Single instead of .SingleOrDefault and the object I get back is null, not 'sequence contains no elements' error. When I use SQL profiler and capture the SQL that is generated, I run the query and get 1 result. What would cause the object to be null?

Thanks for any help,
~ck

Comment: Voted to close. You should update your original question with your new findings. It's only 3 days old: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579164/linq-help-sql-trace-returns-result-but-datacontext-returning-null

Comment: This is different.  He's getting null with Single which according to the documentation should either return an object or throw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps your field/properties mapping in your DBML is not correct

Comment: I doubled checked them and they do seem correct. They are all present anyways. I will check the data types.

Comment: It was a connectionstring issue. Pointing to the wrong database. Im an idiot. How can I close this question?